# Haskell IO monad and do notation

Tags: haskell, io, monads

The following Haskell snippit will not compile and I can't figure out why.

```
runCompiler :: TC -> IO ()
runCompiler tc = let cp' = cp in 
    do 
        cp'
        return ()
    where
    cp = compileProg tc
```

I am getting the following error from GHCi:

```
    Couldn't match expected type `IO a0' with actual type `String'
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: cp'
    In the expression:
      do { cp';
           return () }
    In the expression:
      let cp' = cp
      in
        do { cp';
             return () }
```

Any ideas what to do to make it compile. I can't see why it will not accept () as the final value given.

Comment: What is the type signature of compileProg?

Comment: Why are you binding `compileProg tc` to both `cp'` and `cp`? And why are you using both a `let` and a `where` in the same function? It's confusing.

Comment: When I change it to the answer below it compiles. Now my issue is to make it output the String returned by compileProg.

Answer (score 13):

When using `do` notation sequencing two statements:

```
do
    action1
    action2
```

is the same as `action1 >> action2`

since `>>` has type `Monad m => m a -> m b -> m b` both `action1` and `action2` should be monadic values.

It appears your `compileProg` function has type `TC -> String`, while the compiler expects it to be `TC -> IO a` for some `a` since you are using it in `do` notation.

You can use a `let`

```
do 
    let _ = compileProg tc
    return ()
```

to get it to compile.

If you want to output the returned string, you can use `putStrLn` or `print`:

```
do
    putStrLn (compileProg tc)
    return ()
```

since `putStrLn` has type `String -> IO ()` you can remove the `return ()`:

```
do
    putStrLn (compileProg tc)
```

In fact `runCompiler` can be written simply as

```
runCompiler :: TC -> IO ()
runCompiler = putStrLn . compileProg
```

Comment: What I'm wanting to do is display the output of compileProg on screen.
The type signature of compileProg is TC -> String.

Comment: @StuartPaton then you want `putStrLn (compileProc tc)`

Comment: To clarify @lee's answer: each statement in a `do` block much have a type of `IO a` (or it can be a `let` binding). `cp'` has a type of `String`, so it won't type check.

Comment: @drquicksilver Your answer compiles but when I run the program it then exits as normal without displaying anything to the screen. What happens is I hit escape after text is typed in and runCompiler is called, then it ends as normal without anything outputted.

Comment: @StuartPaton well Lee has edited his answer into something fairly complete; if you don't see anything on screen then making compileProc is producing an empty string or maybe it's never being called. I would look at Lee's answer and/or provide more code about what you're actually calling.

Comment: Slight mistake where you put `return (putStrLn ...`.  There shouldn't be a return.  Great answer, though.